# How to find the number of broadcast domains and collision domains with VLANs

Tags: networking, routes, router

Lets assume a switch has 12 ports and 10 of them are in VLAN12,VLAN13 and VLAN14.

How many broadcast domains and collision domains are there?

What happened to that free two ports. Do they assign to the Default VLAN?

Answer (score 0):

So, every port, that is connected to the router(switch) is collision domain and every VLAN is broadcast domain. But there is no the physical scheme of your network, so I can't say more accurately. And yes, Default VLAN ID is assigned to the free ports. Look at these pictures. I hope, they will help you. [Hub: 1 broadcast - 1 collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jYNM.png)  ; [Switch: 1 broadcast - 4 collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UU7X.png) ; [Switch+Router: 2 broadcast - 6 collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICqfg.png)